# c++ default argument error in Windows Universal

Tags: c++, windows, win-universal-app

The line of code (trace) compiles just fine for WinDesktop, Android, iOS, but not for Windows Universal. This is my own string class. Arrays and char pointer have always been the same. If I try to add a ctor for a wchar_t array, it immediately says that I already have that constructor. What am I missing?

```
namespace Couloir
{
   class String
   {
      private:
        wstring Value;

       public:
         String();
         String( const String& cs );
         String( String&& cs );
         String( const wstring& );
         String( wstring&& );
         String( const wchar_t* );

         void trace( const String& contextualFormat = L"\n\r%s\n\r" ) const;
         //....
   };
}
```

Error:

```
Error   C2440   'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [7]' to 'const Couloir::String &'
```

Update: Turning off /ZW (Consume Windows Runtime Extension) results in no errors/warnings. Why would this be?  I need to have this turned on, in order to live large in the WinU world.

Update 2: with /ZW turned off (fixes all errors), and const removed (i.e. void trace(  String& contextualFormat = L"\n\r%s\n\r" ) const;), the same error comes back. It's like /ZW causes the const keyword to be invisible?

Comment: You are missing some source code to get some help. :)

Comment: What's a `Couloir::String`?

Comment: bash0r, thanks for responding. What else would you like to see?

Comment: You are assigning a `const wchar_t[7]` value to a const *reference*. There is no object creation.

Comment: @SimonKraemer, what do you suggest? The following didn't fix the error.

`void trace( String& contextualFormat = L"\n\r%s\n\r" ) const;`

Remember that in addition to Clang 3.6, the same compiler (msvc) is happy with this LOC when compiling for WinDesktop. I compared the compiler options but could find no significant difference.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I thought the reference would cause the problem but it compiles just fine. Does it work for other platforms if you just write the assignment in some function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently is a compiler error reporting bug. It was fixed by adding the namespace:

```
void trace( const Couloir::String& contextualFormat = L"\n\r%s\n\r" ) const;
```

The error is that it reported "const Couloir::String&", indicating that when it went to report the error, it knew that String referred to Couloir::String. However, when it was analyzing the error, it thought it was Platform::String.